# Array of Pointers to Type

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers, types

I missed my class today thanks to my car breaking down. Would array of pointers to type be something like the the following?

```
void *ary[10];
ary[0] = new int();
ary[1] = new float();
```

I'm still kinda fuzzy on what it is.

Comment: please be a bit more specific?

Comment: @nima Ganjehloo  best excuse ever

Comment: I swear haha. Tt was the engine mount that broke. Whenever I accelerated the engine was pulling itself out of the hood, and as a result the torque bar broke :P Anyway its fixed now. I'd never miss class haha

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If this is `C` code, there are a few things to point out. First off (as mentioned below), `new` is not valid `C`. It is valid in `C++`, but you cannot allocate memory this way in `C`. Instead, you will need to use `malloc()` to allocate memory and `free()` in lieu of C++'s `delete` (these functions are included by `#include <stdlib.h>`).

Now, in response to your comment. It seems like you are confused as to what a pointer actually is. A pointer is something which *points* to a location in memory. That is, a pointer is of some type on your system (i.e. maybe an `unsigned long`) which ultimately holds some number. This number is the memory location of some data which you allocated (note that in practice due to virtual memory, these numbers do *not* correspond directly to the physical RAM addresses).

So in `C` when you do something like below

```
char* x = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
```

You allocate a chunk of memory which for a single `char`. The return value from `malloc()` is a `void*` which is why we casted it to `char*` since that is what we want to use this memory as. This `void*` is the location to the memory you requested (by calling `malloc()`) which the operating system assigned to you for use. In order to actually use this memory, you need to dereference (i.e. the `*` operator) the memory location. So after we have this memory allocated, we can try something like

```
*x = 'a';
```

Now the value at memory location `x` is `a`. In code, this can be denoted

```
if(*x == 'a')
  printf("True");
```

It is important to note that `sizeof(int*) == sizeof(char*)` even though `sizeof(int) != sizeof(char)`. This is an important distinction. Notice how the first comparison compares sizes of pointer addresses and the second compares the size of the data structures (or, in this case, type primitives). The reason that this is important is that it enables your code above to actually work. Since all pointer addresses are of equal size, you can create an array of `void*` and store any pointer type you wish in it without overwriting the buffer (i.e. each pointer nicely fits in `array[i]` respectively). The power of `void*` is that you can pass anything as a `void*` (yes, you can technically cast anything to anything else, but this is convenient at times). The major loss of `void*`, however, is that you cannot *directly* use it. That said, if I have code like this:

```
void passData(void* data)
{
  char* x = (char*)data; // I _must_ do this to access the data
  printf("%s\n", x);
}

int main()
{
  char* x = (char*)malloc(10*sizeof(char));
  *x = "test";
  passData((void*)test);
  free(x);
  return 0;
}
```

I have to know my data type to use the `void*` (or you must use metadata or similar to know how to handle this).

Now that we have some basis on memory allocation and what pointers actually do, I will address your comment. Since pointers simply point to memory addresses, if you have two pointers which point to the *same* memory address, then you simply have to ways of accessing the same data. For instance, consider the snippet below

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int x = 0; // Stack variable

  int* xPtr = &x; // & is the reference operator - it gives you the memory location of an object

  x = 5;

  printf("%d == %d\n", x, *xPtr); // xPtr == 5 since it points to the same memory location as x

  *xPtr = 10;

  printf("%d == %d\n", x, *xPtr); // x == 10 since we changed the value at the memory location of xPtr which is the same memory location which x is located at

  return 0;
}
```

If you are not yet too familiar with the concept of pointers, this example below may be slightly clearer since it deals purely with heap memory:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int* xPtr = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
  int* yPtr = xPtr; // Point yPtr to the same address as xPtr

  *xPtr = 10; // The value of xPtr == 10 and so does the value of yPtr since they point to the same place
  *yPtr = 12; // In a similar way, we modified the value again for both pointers.

  yPtr = NULL; // Unset the memory location of yPtr - now yPtr no longer points to the same memory location as xPtr.
               // In fact, now yPtr == NULL, so do _NOT_ try to dereference it or you will crash. In any event, the values of the pointers are now independent

  *xPtr = 15; // Memory at the location xPtr points to has changed to 15. But yPtr no longer points to that location, so the value at the location yPtr points to has not changed.

  yPtr = xPtr; // Change the memory location of yPtr to point to xPtr. Now yPtr's value is exactly the same as xPtr's value.

  free(xPtr); // Only free ONE of the items pointing to the same memory location (otherwise you will double free)
  return 0;
}
```

As you can see, you are simply accessing data in particular locations in memory. The pointer just points to that location in memory. Moving pointers around and making them point to different locations is known as `pointer manipulation`. So that is why you can change memory at one location and it changes the value for any other pointer which points to that memory location.

**Original Response** (Question originally tagged `C++`)

In reality, what you have done is more `C-style`. This is technically valid (as long as you cast), but to do anything with these types later, you would have to know *exactly* what type is in what position and cast it back appropriately.

In the example you have given, you created an array which can hold `void` pointers. That is, `void*` is pretty much any "vanilla" type (since you can technically cast to anything but if you do not access the memory appropriately you are sure to crash). But you cannot dereference or do any real work on a `void*` so you need to know what the memory actually is in order to cast it back. In any event, it is good to note that in `C++` it is considered good practice to not use `()` for default/empty constructors - so simply `new float;` will do fine.

The reason you can do this without messing anything up (i.e. different data structures have different sizes) is because pointers are simply `ptr_t` types (on many machines maybe an `unsigned long` or similar). So, realistically, the pointer just points to some location in memory, but all pointers (i.e. the addresses) are of equal size even if the objects the point to are different sizes.

In `C++` it is better to use polymorphism to do this. For instance, create an array of "Ball" pointers which all are (at least with a base class of) of the class `Ball`. Then, you can make them more specific. For instance, you could have a baseball, basketball, etc.

I am not entirely sure what you are trying without proper context, but this should look something like this

```
#include <isotream>
using namespace std;
class Ball
{
public:
  virtual void ballType() const = 0;
};

class Basketball : public Ball
{
public:
  virtual void ballType() const {
    cout << "Basketball" << endl;
  }
};

class Baseball : public Ball
{
public:
  virtual void ballType() const {
    cout << "Baseball" << endl;
  }
};
```

Then, in general, if you use this as follows:

```
Ball* x[10];
x[0] = new Basketball;
x[1] = new Baseball;

x[0]->ballType();
x[1]->ballType();

delete x[0];
delete x[1];
```

This would print "Basketball" followed by "Baseball." If you could provide some more context as to what you are looking to do, I could tailor this response a little better to target your question.

Comment: And replace `Ball*` with `std::unique_ptr<Ball>`, to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: i forgot to mention that im doing C atm. My class mate was talking about how if you have  two pointers to the same address in the array, changing one changes the other as well... could u elaborate more on that?

Comment: You can't use `new` in C. It's not part of the language.

Comment: sorry for the late response. I really appreciate the elaborate explanation. I don't know how to thank u other than giving u an up-vote. :P Once again thank you so much for the response.

Answer (score 1):

the pointer is an "integer" number it can point to anything you want in memory, if you have void *array it says that you have a void pointer called array, now depends how you use it you can have it type casted to int or other things and objects.

if you use void *array[10] that creates an array of pointers, now how you use the pointers its up to you. You can create objects or assign them to what ever data type you want,but this is not type safe since it`s a void pointer without type specification. it also requires strong type casting for usage with data types.

Technically you can have every pointer with different data type inside that array.

Comment: Pointers aren't integers, they're ptr_t. This is typically an integer. The point of me pointing it out is that it being an integer isn't really relevant, it's just a variable that represents an address in memory

Comment: well that is the reason why i said "integers" not plainly integers in reality when you look at the pointer its a number 123451235 from which is an integer from math perspective.

Comment: You can't use the [] to create a list. It's an array. What do you understand under "strong type casting", what would be "weak"? You won't have any other pointer than a void* in the array, but you are allowed to have pointers that point to anything including pointing to every data type and any kind of function. Except: member function pointers.

Comment: sorry it was my typo with list ,by list i meant an array of pointers. by strong type casting i mean where you explicitly use (int) , the weak one is when is implicit like for example when you save integer value to a float ( float a= 1; ) in this case 1 is an integer being "weak casted" to float .